# Detecting if a word is valid when it contains a blank

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm working on a phone based word game, and there could potentially be quite a few blanks (representing any letter) that a player could have the option to use.

I store all the possible words in a hashSet, so detecting if a word is valid when it has one blank is simply a matter of looping through the alphabet replacing the blank with a letter and testing the word. I have a recursive call so this will work with any number of blanks. The code is as follows:

```
public boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    if (word.contains(" ")){
        for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
            if (isValidWord(word.replaceFirst(" ", Character.toString(i))))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    else
        return wordHashSet.contains(word);
}
```

As the number of blanks increases, the number of words we have to test increase exponentially. By the time we get to 3 blanks we're having to do 17576 lookups before we can reject a word, and this is affecting game play. Once there are 4 blanks the game will just freeze for a while.

What is the most efficient way for me to check words with multiple blanks. Should I just iterate through the hashset and check if we have a match against each word? If so, then what's the fastest way for me to compare two strings taking the blanks into account? I've tried doing this using a regular expression and String.matches(xx), but it's too slow. A straight String.equals(xx) is fast enough, but that obviously doesn't take blanks into account.

Comment: you should be able to subset the hash based on the first blank - only keeping possible matches - then repeat only on that subset

Comment: @Randy how can I efficiently subset the hastset without using regular expressions as they're too slow.

Comment: construct a new hash with the smaller set only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very fast method althrough somewhat challenging to implement would be to store your words in a Trie - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

A trie is a tree structure that contains a char in every node and an array of pointers pointing to next nodes.

Without blank spaces it would be easy - just follow the trie structure, you can check this in linear time. When you have a blank, you will have a loop to search all possible routes.

This can sound complicated and difficult if you are not familiar with tries but if you get stuck I can help you with some code.

EDIT:

Ok, here is some c# code for your problem using tries, I think you will have no problems converting it in JAVA. If you do, leave a comment and I will help.

Trie.cs

```
public class Trie
{

    private char blank = '_';

    public Node Root { get; set; }

    public void Insert(String key)
    {
        Root = Insert(Root, key, 0);
    }

    public bool Contains(String key)
    {
        Node x = Find(Root, key, 0);
        return x != null && x.NullNode;
    }

    private Node Find(Node x, String key, int d)
    { // Return value associated with key in the subtrie rooted at x.
        if (x == null)
            return null;

        if (d == key.Length)
        {
            if (x.NullNode)
              return x;
            else
              return null;
        }

        char c = key[d]; // Use dth key char to identify subtrie.

        if (c == blank)
        {
            foreach (var child in x.Children)
            {
                var node = Find(child, key, d + 1);
                if (node != null)
                    return node;
            }

            return null;
        }
        else
            return Find(x.Children[c], key, d + 1);
    }

    private Node Insert(Node x, String key, int d)
    { // Change value associated with key if in subtrie rooted at x.
        if (x == null) x = new Node();
        if (d == key.Length)
        {
            x.NullNode = true;
            return x;
        }

        char c = key[d]; // Use dth key char to identify subtrie.
        x.Children[c] = Insert(x.Children[c], key, d + 1);
        return x;
    }

    public IEnumerable<String> GetAllKeys()
    {
        return GetKeysWithPrefix("");
    }
    public IEnumerable<String> GetKeysWithPrefix(String pre)
    {
        Queue<String> q = new Queue<String>();
        Collect(Find(Root, pre, 0), pre, q);
        return q;
    }

    private void Collect(Node x, String pre, Queue<String> q)
    {
        if (x == null) return;
        if (x.NullNode) q.Enqueue(pre);
        for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
            Collect(x.Children[c], pre + ((char)c), q);
    }
}
```

Node.cs

```
public class Node
{
    public bool NullNode { get; set; }

    public Node[] Children { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        NullNode = false;
        Children = new Node[256];
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
Trie tr = new Trie();
tr.Insert("telephone");
while (true)
{
     string str = Console.ReadLine();
     if( tr.Contains( str ) )
         Console.WriteLine("contains!");
     else
         Console.WriteLine("does not contain!");
}
```

Comment: forgot to add, blank space is "\_". So a valid test case would be "tel_phon\_" for example.

Comment: Only just got round to implementing this... works perfectly. I reduced the size of the child array to 26 to save memory. Still takes up twice as much as the hashset solution. Works well though - thanks.

Comment: Quick Q - I'm guessing you've used these structures in the past. Have you ever tried replacing the child array with a Dictionary/Hashmap to save memory? I might try it out if you haven't.... if you have, I'm guessing it didn't work?

Comment: @Will Sure, it will work. I used the array just to try to maximize performance at the cost of some memory.

Comment: Just fixed a small bug in the code. I noticed it was returning ____ as an invalid word - as I know there is at least one 4 letter word in the English language I figured something was wrong! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> A straight String.equals(xx) is fast enough, but that obviously
>   doesn't take blanks into account.

So I recommend to implement this simple solution, which is very close to `String.equals()`, and takes blanks into account:

```
public boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    if (wordHashSet.contains(word)) {
        return true;
    }
    for (String fromHashSet: wordHashSet){
        if (compareIgnoreBlanks(fromHashSet, word)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Inspired by String.compareTo(String). Compares two String's, ignoring blanks in the String given as
 * second argument.
 * 
 * @param s1
 *            String from the HashSet
 * @param s2
 *            String with potential blanks
 * @return true if s1 and s2 match, false otherwise
 */
public static boolean compareIgnoreBlanks(String s1, String s2) {
    int len = s1.length();
    if (len != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    int k = 0;
    while (k < len) {
        char c1 = s1.charAt(k);
        char c2 = s2.charAt(k);
        if (c2 != ' ' && c1 != c2) {
            return false;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the fastest method I've tried so far. I think it might be fast enough, although the blank comparisons aren't working. I'll debug shortly.

Comment: I was passing my strings to the method the wrong way round. Working now, thanks. I'll do a few more tests and look at the Trie option before I accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of ugly, but I would guess fairly fast method would be to create a string containing all valid words like this:

```
WORD1
WORD2
WORD3
```

etc.

Then use a regex like `(^|\n)A[A-Z]PL[A-Z]\n` (i.e. replacing all blanks with `[A-Z]`), and match it on that string.

Comment: How do you suggest I create the list of valid words efficiently?

Comment: Keep it as a static variable in the class and use a StringBuilder to create it in a loop: `for(String word : words) sb.append(word).append("\n");`

Comment: How do I identify a valid word?

Comment: Use a the RegEx pattern I posted and match against the string containing all the words. if `Matcher.find()` returns `true`, the word is valid. Note that I modified the RegEx in my post, since it was incorrect.

Comment: Is it really too slow if only run once? I can understand it being too slow if matching one word at a time, but once on a large string should be quite fast. (Though granted I haven't tested this on any larger scale)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    word = word.replaceAll(" ", "[a-z]");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word);

    for (String wordFromHashSet: hashSet){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(wordFromHashSet);
        if (matcher.matches()) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: OP already tried this approach: _I've tried doing this using a regular expression and String.matches(xx), but it's too slow_.

Comment: I just tried this, as it's a slightly different approach. Still too slow unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isValidWord(String word) {
    ArrayList<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i!=word.length();i++){
        if (word.charAt(i) == ' ') pos.add(i);
    }

    for (String hashSetWord: hashSet){
        for (Integer i: pos){
            hashSetWord = hashSetWord.substring(0,i)+" "+hashSetWord.substring(i+1);            
        }
        if (hashSetWord.equals(word)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Still too slow I'm afraid

Comment: One iteration throw all words. And few replacements for every word. I think u can't do this faster..